# Вопрос по массивам С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Почему нельзя задать размер статического массива обычной переменной, а только константой, например такой код не скомпилируется :

```
int SIZE = 10;
int arr[SIZE];
```

Comment: есть VLA, так что все компилируется. Другое дело, что Ваш компилятор такое не поддерживает. Но это си. А в плюсах для этого есть std::vector - используйте его там, где Вам хочется использовать обычный массив.

Comment: std::vector юзай. Напихивать массив на стек плохая идея.

Comment: почему это плохая идея? стек - это "быстрая и дешевая" память (если вы понимаете о чем я)

Comment: С++ компиляторы  должен знать сколько памяти выделить для стека, для массива. А раз  размер не константный, вы можете его значение изменять во время выполнения, а значит изменится и размер  стека(массива).   Таким образом ваш код защищается от неопределенного поведения....

Comment: компилятор легко может выделить нужное кол-во памяти в стеке "на лету". иначе та же alloca была бы невозможной.

Comment: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097)?

Comment: @KoVadim потому что стек не резиновый и мои 100000 элементов в него не факт что влезут.

Comment: не знаю, как ваши, а мои влезут.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan "А раз размер не константный, вы можете его значение изменять во время выполнения" - я перечитал несколько раз, очень спорная фраза. То, что размер массива не константный ещё не значит, что кто то будет менять размер массива. И компиляторы давно уже сильно умнее. они не "выделяют память для стека" - этим занимается операционная среда, а линковщик может попросить "поменять размер".

Comment: @KoVadim, не значит что кто то будет менять, но могут явно или неявно менять. А потом вызывать функцию, работающую  с массивом, и которая не знает, что этот размер изменен.  ОС выделяет память для стека в  результате  работы компилятора или компоновщика. По этому поводу я рядом в скобках написал "массива", потому что в данном примере в стеке только объект хранящий размер и массив, и размер стека зависит только от размера массива, который по выше указанным причинам, должен быть известен компилятору.

Comment: "А потом вызывать функцию, работающую с массивом, и которая не знает, что этот размер изменен" кем изменен? можно пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что этот массив СТАТИЧЕСКИЙ, т.е. его размер задаётся на стадии компиляции, а не выполнения. Если такой массив определён, как глобальная переменная (т.е., объявлен вне тела какой-либо функции, либо с модификатором static), то его размер добавляется к общему размеру всех непроинициализированных глобальных переменных программы, память под эти переменные выделяется системой целиком на стадии загрузки. По-этому в рантайме размеры подобных массивов изменить уже нельзя, компилятору нужно знать их заранее, а значит в качестве них допустимы только константы.

Однако, если же массив определяется, как локальная переменная какой-либо функции, то поскольку выделение памяти под него в стеке (вместе с другими локальными переменными) осуществляется во время выполнения, современные компиляторы, как например GCC, позволяют задавать размер таких массивов динамически, в виде других переменных.
Например, следующий код рабочий (проверил в GCC):

```
void func(int size)
{
    char arr[size];
    arr[size-1] = 0;
}
```

А вот этот код, по указанным выше причинам, уже не скомпилируется:

```
void func(int size)
{
    static char arr[size];
    arr[size-1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: А gcc компилит этот код в функции. А ещё есть alloca.

Comment: эта функция поддерживатся нормальными компиляторами си и называется VLA, а недавно говорят даже студия начала поддерживать

Comment: @KoVadim надо же, как говорится, век живи - век учись)) Возможность, на самом деле, очень хорошая. Я такое применял в процедурах, которые писал на ассемблере, как быструю альтернативу динамическому выделения памяти. Оказывается, теперь это и на высоком уровне доступно. Спасибо, буду знать))

Comment: только не теперь, а уже много много лет. И кстати сам ответ очень странный. Боюсь его заминусуют

Comment: @KoVadim только теперь я про это узнал. До этого момента как-то не было повода поинтересоваться, ибо времена, когда я активно изучал программирование и штудировал книги по C++, остались в далёких нулевых. С тех пор пополнял свой багаж знаний по мере необходимости и случая (вот как сейчас). Ответ свой с учётом новых (для меня) сведений поправил, надеюсь, что теперь не сильно заминусуют.

Comment: @LShadow77, [Extensions to the C Language Family](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) (enjoy -))

Comment: Все зависит от компилятора. А если зависит, значит не нужно  создавать массив таким образом.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, и как много вы знаете систем, куда gcc еще не портировали?

Comment: @avp, Причем тут доступность компиляторов?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, а что по вашему обеспечивает переносимость кода? (вы же говорите именно о ней в своем комментарии -- *`"Все зависит от компилятора. А если зависит, значит не нужно создавать массив таким образом"`*)

Comment: @avp,  а почему "не нужно" обязательно должно означать "не переносимо". Это означает, что  программу компилирует конкретная программа, и с какой стати я должен использовать ту или иную только ради того, чтобы объявить массив?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, вы можете использовать любые программы

Comment: @avp, Я не говорил, что не можете.  Не получается понять друг друга. Ну ладно,  значит продолжение не следует....